# Pandas + py2exe error: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, py2exe

I have a very simple program in python that works perfectly within Spyder or Eclipse, but fails when executed in the command line after it was pacakged with py2exe.

OS is a French Windows 7 and I am using:
Python 3.4.1 from Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)
Pandas 0.15.2               np19py34_0
cython 0.21.2

The error I get is the following one:

```
Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipextimporter.py", line 86, in load_module
    return zipimport.zipimporter.load_module(self, fullname)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipextimporter.py", line 109, in load_module self.get_data)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 9, in init pandas.hashtable (pandas\hashtable.c:23000)
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

Here is the main.py coding:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pandas
data = pandas.read_hdf ("C:/temp/test.h5", "MainData")
file = open ("C:/temp/log.txt", "a+")
strMessage = ""
for arg in data.columns:
    strMessage += str (arg) + "\n"
file.write (strMessage)
file.close()
```

and the setup.py:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

excludes = ['tkinter']
opts = {'py2exe': {'excludes':excludes,
                   'bundle_files': 1,
                   'compressed': True,
                   'optimize':2}}

setup(name='Core',
      version='1.0',
      description = "Core Engine",
      console = [{"script": "Main.py",
                  "dest_base": "Core"}],
      options = opts)
```

I'm executing the following command line to build my executable file:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda3, upgrading pandas and cython with "conda" and/or "pip" but nothing worked.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: FYI, I have downgraded pandas to version 0.14.1 and it works with this version.
However I really need pandas 0.15.2 as it fixes issues that are important to me and other packages such as "seaborn" are not compatible with the older version.

Comment: Well, I downgraded pandas to version 0.14.1, but I'm still having the same problem. Is there something else you tried?

Comment: I also removed the 'bundle_files' and 'optimize' options.  
I've read somewhere that 'bundle_files':1 is not compatible with Windows 7 64bits yet.

Comment: Yes, removing `bundle_files` fixed it. So, the workaround would be to downgrade to pandas 0.14.1 **and** remove the `bundle_files` option. Unfortunately, I need a single-file executable (`'bundle_files': 0`), so I'm still looking for a real solution.

Comment: Yes I believe that could be the workaround. But like you I do need a single-file executable and I also need pandas 0.15.2. So hopefully, someone will find a solution.  
Or maybe the guys developping Pandas/Py2exe will fix the issue...

Comment: I had the same issue, but I only needed to remove the `bundle_files` option, keeping pandas 0.15.2, to get an executable compiled. Session info: Win 7; python 3.4 (64-bit, Anaconda); py2exe 0.9.2.2.